scanner app using zebra hardware in react native
I am trying to build an app for scanning inventory. The app is being build using React Native. Check on their website. The comments say support is outdated or deprecated.
Are there any packages for capturing the scan. Or any tutorials for how the make a basic example?
I have tried to install Data Wedge and could not get it to work.
